# how do i display only a specific row in lookerstudio table?

Tags: looker-studio

I want to show only the nth row of a table. If i limit the rows to display, it still shows the first row. How do I see only the 2nd row or 3rd row and so on?

So for example if I want to know the 5th best player and only display their name, how do I do that?

I have tried a lot by looking on Google but found no answer on any community

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not possible in looker studio as there is no "row_number" function or anything like that. This must be done in the data source.